# clearInterval not working in javascript chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extension and in my `content script` which runs only on `www.youtube.com` it's supposed to check, `document.getElementById("movie_player")`, if a particular `div` element has loaded or not. If not `setInterval` and wait a second. If it has loaded then run `alert("Hello")` and `clearInterval` which will end the script.

However, it's not working. Even after I find the element, and it says "Hello" it continues to say hello which means `setInterval` is still calling my function after 1000 milliseconds even though it should have been cleared.

Here's my `content.js` file:

```
var timeOut;

function CheckDOMChange()
{   
    moviePlayer = document.getElementById("movie_player");

    if(moviePlayer !== null)
        {
            WhenVideoLoads();
        }

    timeOut = setInterval("CheckDOMChange();", 1000);
}
function WhenVideoLoads()
{
    alert("Hello");

    clearInterval(timeOut);
}
CheckDOMChange();
```

As you can see, I made `timeOut` a global variable so it shouldn't be a scope problem. So I really don't know what the problem is because the condition is being met and `clearInterval` is being called.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @FastSnail That isn't the problem. You can call the function either way. Even after changing my code I still get the same output.

Comment: Apart from the answers, you should also avoid using quoted functions inside setInterval or setTimeout. Instead of `"CheckDOMChange();"` you should use `CheckDOMChange`. The quoted variant is a form of "eval" and probably breaks your code in minifiers and other code checkers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have `setInterval` inside the function. Basically, for every call you are setting interval which creates multiple setIntervals. Remove the setInterval from within the function

```
var timeOut;

function CheckDOMChange() {
  moviePlayer = document.getElementById("movie_player");

  if (moviePlayer !== null) {
    WhenVideoLoads();
  }


}

function WhenVideoLoads() {
  alert("Hello");

  clearInterval(timeOut);
}
timeOut = setInterval("CheckDOMChange();", 1000);
```

Comment: You were right. I suspected this might be the problem but was unsure. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

By calling `CheckDOMChange` recursively, you are actually exponentially creating timers, and you are only clearing the last timer when calling `WhenVideoLoads`.

You may try to run this snippet and inspect the console to see what is happening, and see that clicking the button will clear the last timer but not all those that have been created before.

```js
var timeOut;
var counter = 0;

function CheckDOMChange()
{   
 console.log("counter :", counter);
  if (counter > 16) {
    console.log("Stop creating new timers!");
    return;
   }

  timeOut = setInterval("CheckDOMChange();", 5000);
 console.log("timeOut :", timeOut);
 counter ++;
}
function WhenVideoLoads()
{
  console.log("Clearing ", timeOut);
  clearInterval(timeOut);
}
CheckDOMChange();
```

```html
<button onclick="WhenVideoLoads()" id="clear">Clear timer</button>
```

You should avoid calling `CheckDOMChange` recursively, and proceed as @cdoshi suggested.

Hope this helps!